# trying to make my (very simple) libgdx game more object-oriented. added GameObject class - game doesn't launch anymore

Tags: java, android, object, libgdx, 2d

what the title says.

first of all, here are my 3 classes:

**MyGdxGame**:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite sp; 
    Texture img;
    int width;
    int height; 
    Player p;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("dildo.png");
        sp = new Sprite(img); 
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        p = new Player(img);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(p);

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        //sp.flip(true, false);
        p.update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255,255,255,255);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        //batch.draw(img, 0, height/6, -img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        p.draw(batch);
        //sp.draw(batch); 
        batch.end();
    }
    }
```

**Player**:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class Player extends GameObject implements InputProcessor {

    private Sprite sp;
    private Texture te;
    private float xPos;
    private float yPos;
    private float xSpeed;
    private float ySpeed;
    private float accelerationX;
    private float g;
    Vector2 position;
    private float accelerationJump = 9f;
    private boolean allowJump = true;
    private boolean isDragged = false;

        public Player(Texture sprite) {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = (super.getHeight()/6);
        xSpeed = 5.5f;
        ySpeed = 0;
        te = sprite;
        sp.setX(xPos);
        sp.setY(yPos);
        g = 0.2f;
        accelerationX=0.02f;

    }

    public void update() {
        ySpeed -= g;

        if(isDragged) {
            xSpeed += accelerationX;
            moveBy(xSpeed,0);
            isDragged = false;
        }

        if (getxPos() > super.getWidth()) {
            setxPos(0);
        } else {
            moveBy(xSpeed, ySpeed);
        }

        if (getyPos() < super.getHeight() / 6) {
            moveTo(sp.getX(), getHeight() / 6);
        }
        if (onGround()) {
            allowJump = true;
            ySpeed = 0;
        }
    }

    public void jump() {
        ySpeed += accelerationJump;
    }

    public boolean onGround() {
        return (sp.getY() == super.getHeight()/6);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if (allowJump && isDragged == false) {
            allowJump = false;
            jump(); 
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        if(isDragged==false) {
        isDragged = true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GameObject**:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public abstract class GameObject {

    private Sprite sp;

    private int width;

    private int height;

    private float xPos;

    private float yPos;

    private float xSpeed;

    private float ySpeed;

    public GameObject(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public GameObject() {

    }

    public void moveTo(float xPos2, float yPos2) {
        setxPos(xPos2);
        setyPos(yPos2);
    }

    public void moveBy(float dx, float dy) {
        sp.setY(sp.getY() + dy);
        sp.setX(sp.getX() + dx);
    }

    public float getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public float getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setxPos(float xPos2) {
        sp.setX(xPos2);
    }

    public void setyPos(float yPos) {
        sp.setY(yPos);
    }

    public float getxSpeed() {
        return xSpeed;
    }

    public float getySpeed() {
        return ySpeed;
    }

    public void setxSpeed(float xSpeed2) {
        xSpeed = xSpeed2;
    }

    public void setySpeed(float ySpeed2) {
        ySpeed = ySpeed2;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        sp.draw(batch);
    }

}
```

basically, the game as it is now is just a sprite moving from left to right of the screen - when you tap, it jumps, when you drag the screen it dashes forward. i want to now start adding things like power-ups and platforms so i thought it would be a good idea to create a GameObject class. but now when i run it the screen goes black and the application just crashes, i have a feeling it has something to do with the way i'm initialising my Texture? any ideas?

any help is highly appreciated, many thanks in advance :)

edit: in GameObject constructor width and height are the width and height of the screen

Answer (score 0):

if you have your image in asset folder of android project, test `img = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal ("dildo.png"));`

example:
AdroidProyect->Asset->YourFile.png

and in player i think
1-

```
public Player(Texture sprite) {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = (super.getHeight()/6);
        xSpeed = 5.5f;
        ySpeed = 0;
        te = sprite;
```

//add and refactor your code if it works

```
  sp = new Sprite(sprite);




        sp.setX(xPos);
        sp.setY(yPos);
        g = 0.2f;
        accelerationX=0.02f;

    }
```

or 2-
I do not want to do, but in your MyGdxGame, your
you say,

```
..//
    img = new Texture ("dildo.png");
             sp = new Sprite (img);
             p = new Player (img);
..//
```

but after you pass the player a texture, because no sprite or as I said before initializing the player, you could also change the constructor of the player.

```
public Player(Sprite sprite){t
..//
this.sp = sprite;
```

ADD NEW:

Musta Been to look at your code and no offense, you have a code a little crazy :)

visibility of variables is somewhat confusing because what you want but do not test well and looks over the access modifiers, aver if they match what you want to do.
my English is also a little crazy too.

in your class MyGdxGame;
..//

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("dildo.png"));
    sp = new Sprite(img); 
    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    p = new Player(sp);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(p);

}
```

..//

class GameObject Change;

```
public abstract class GameObject {

protected Sprite sp;

protected int width;

protected int height;

protected float xPos;

protected float yPos;

protected float xSpeed;

protected float ySpeed;
```

player class.

```
public class Player extends GameObject implements InputProcessor {

//private Sprite sp;   remove
private Texture te;   
//private float xPos; remove
//private float yPos; remove
//private float xSpeed; remove
//private float ySpeed; remove
private float accelerationX;
private float g;
Vector2 position;
private float accelerationJump = 9f;
private boolean allowJump = true;
private boolean isDragged = false;

    public Player(Sprite sprite) {
    ..//
    sp = sprite;
```